# Difference between Bubbling and Tunneling events

Tags: wpf, events, event-handling

What is the exact difference between Bubbling Events and Tunneling events?

Where should I use Bubbling Events and where should I use Tunneling events?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> WPF gives us a number of different mechanisms for handling events –
>   they are bubbling, tunneling, and direct. These are all known as
>   Routed events.
>
> **Direct event**
>
> You are probably already used to the direct routed event. This is
>   where the item itself handles the event that occurred. A good example
>   would be handling he `onClick`-event of a mouse button in standard
>   WinForms. This is where the event is raised in the GUI item and gets
>   handled by said GUI element.
>
> **Bubbling Event**
>
> Now we all like some bubbles in one form or another. Bubbling happens
>   when the event is not handled by the element ( say a `textbox`) and the
>   event "bubbles" its way up the UI containers which hold it. For
>   example, let's say you have a window that contains a panel and inside
>   that panel you have a grid and inside the grid you have a textbox. If
>   the event is not handled by the textbox, then it moves, is passed or
>   "bubbles" up to the grid level (as the grid contains the textbox), if
>   it is not handled at that level then the event bubbles further up the
>   "tree" (known as a visual tree) to the panel where it may or may not
>   be handled. This process continues until it is handled or the event
>   "escapes" the top most element.
>
> Examples of a bubbling event would be something like a
>   `MouseButtonDown` event. Or a `Keydown` event.
>
> **Tunneling**
>
> Tunneling is the opposite of Bubbling. So instead of an event going
>   "up" the visual tree, the event travels down the visual tree toward
>   the element that is considered the source. The standard WPF naming
>   definition of a tunneling event is that they all start with "preview"
>   for example `previewdownkey` and `previewmousebuttondown`. You can
>   catch them on their way to the "target" element and handle it. An
>   example for this might be perhaps you have some controls inside a grid
>   control and for some reason you have decided that no control within
>   that grid will be allowed to have the letter "t" reach it.

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events) with the opinion of the author which I don't support nor agree with.

[And another StackOverflow question which is pretty much the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450765/understanding-routing-events-why-i-need-both-bubble-and-tunnel-events)

<s>[A nice demo project](http://www.wpfmentor.com/2008/11/understand-bubbling-and-tunnelling-in-5.html)</s>

[And last but not least some explanation and another tutorial.](http://wpftutorial.net/RoutedEvents.html)

Comment: Really good explanation, thanks +1.  BTW, the link for "A nice demo project" is now dead.

Answer (score 7):

As a start: the naming convention in WPF for some default events is `Preview<event>` for tunneling and `<event>` for bubbling. So for example for the KeyDown we would have `PreviewKeyDown` and `KeyDown`, tunneling and bubbling respectively.

The difference between the two, as the naming convention implies, is that a tunneling event will start at the highest node in the tree (probably the Window) and going down to the lowest child. A bubbling event will start at the child and then go upwards again.

This guide should explain it clearly:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events