# Button Command doesn't getting executed on CommunityToolKit DataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, winui-3

I'm using `WinUI CommunityToolkit DataGrid` from [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.DataGrid/) nuget package.
here is my data grid definition:

```
<toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Tests, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  MinHeight="500"
                  AreRowDetailsFrozen="False"
                  AreRowGroupHeadersFrozen="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="True"
                  ColumnHeaderHeight="40"
                  FrozenColumnCount="0"
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
                  RowGroupHeaderPropertyNameAlternative="Range">
    <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Records (count)" Tag="RecordsCount" Width="150">
            <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding RecordsCount}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="184">
            <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!-- Click event works but command doesn't getting executed -- >
                        <Button Width="40" Height="40" 
                                Command="{Binding ViewModel.DeleteTestCommand, ElementName=testPage}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}">
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="40" Height="40"
                                Command="{Binding ViewModel.EditTestCommand, ElementName=testPage}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}">
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```

here is my view model:

```
public partial class TestsPageViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    public IRelayCommand<int> EditTestCommand { get; }

    public IRelayCommand<int> DeleteTestCommand { get; }

    public TestsPageViewModel(ITestsQueryService testsQueryService, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        EditTestCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(EditTest);
        DeleteTestCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(DeleteTest);
       
        Tests = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>(); //(Some tests here);
    }

    public void DeleteTest(int id)
    {
        //var test = Tests.First(P => P.Id == id);
    }

    public void EditTest(int id)
    {
        //var test = Tests.First(P => P.Id == id);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TestModel> Tests 
    { 
        get => _tests;
        set => SetProperty(ref _tests, value); 
    }
}
```

and TestModel contains:

- public int Id { get; set; }
- public int RecordCount { get; set; }
  , ....

As I mentioned in the `Xaml` Click event works for buttons but Commands aren't working at all.

tnx for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a `DataGrid`'s issue (or by design?).

Let me show you 2 workarounds.

A. Use the `Click` event:

**TestPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void EditButton_Click(object sender, e)
{
    if (sender is Button button &&
        button.DataContext is TestModel testModel)
    {
        this.ViewModel.EditTestModelCommand.Execute(testModel.Id);
    }
}
```

B. Add a `EditCommand` on `TestModel`:
**TestModel.cs**

```cs
public partial class TestModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private id;

    public ICommand EditCommand { get; init; }
}
```

**TestViewModel.cs**

```cs
[RelayCommand]
private void EditTestModel(int id)
{
}

// Set the command on each models.
TestModel model = new ()
{
    Id = 1,
    EditCommand = EditTestModel,
};
```

Comment: Tnx a lot I have opened an [Issue](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/4924) in github. I think something like event [tunneling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736444/difference-between-bubbling-and-tunneling-events) happens on commands there.